# How can i add DataID and password in an HTTP header?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, http, c#-4.0, header

How can i add DataID and password in an HTTP header. something like shown below?

POST /serviceCall/ HTTP/1.1
Host    myHost
Content-Length  459
Origin  chrome-extension://cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn
**DataID        25

Password        t123456**

User-Agent      Mozilla/5.0 
Content-Type    application/json
Accept  */*
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

I have tried to add that multiple way

```
s_requestPath  = "http://myServiceCall_URL";
WebRequest s_request = WebRequest.Create(s_requestPath);

// 1st try

            WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = s_request.Headers;
            myWebHeaderCollection.Add("DataID", dataID);
            myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Password", registerViewModel.ConfirmPassword);

//2nd try
            //s_request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential( dataID , registerViewModel.ConfirmPassword);

//3rd try
            //s_request.Headers.Add(" DataID :" +  dataID + ";");
            //s_request.Headers.Add("Password:" + registerViewModel.ConfirmPassword + ";");

//4th try
            //s_request.Headers.Add(" DataID ",  dataID + ";");
            //s_request.Headers.Add("Password", registerViewModel.ConfirmPassword + ";");


            using (StreamWriter s_writer = new StreamWriter(s_request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                s_writer.Write(s_RegJson);    //s_RegJson is json obeject that i am sending
            }
            string rtnJson = "";

            using (WebResponse s_response = s_request.GetResponse())
            {

                using (Stream s_stream = s_response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader r_reader = new StreamReader(s_stream))
                    {
                        while (!r_reader.EndOfStream)
                        {
                             rtnJson  += r_reader.ReadLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to be sending the application/json request header. Try like this:

```
var url = "http://myServiceCall_URL";
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Headers["DataID"] = "25";
request.Headers["Password"] = "t123456";
var requestJson = serializer.Serialize(new
{
    Foo = "bar"
});
request.ContentLength = requestJson.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    writer.Write(requestJson);
}

using (var response = request.GetResponse())
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    var responseJson = reader.ReadToEnd();
    var responseObj = serializer.DeserializeObject(responseJson);
    // do something with the response
}
```

Comment: I tried this but my header looks as below:                         Headers = {Content-Type: application/json
DataID: 63
Password: test123}                                                                                                                                And i get exception The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Comment: Darin, I tried your code also but the request header appears same as before.

Comment: @seUser, the exception you are getting, isn't it related to some server side problem? You seem to mention some INSERT statements and foreign keys. What this has to do with the client?

Comment: Yes, I have reported this to DBA guy. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Hi Darin, what should i do, if i have to make GET request, something like, http://myHost/Player/plays/{PlayID} then what should i do?